# WSL Startup shows "-bash: [: too many arguments"

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Iam using WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) with CentOS7.

When i start the WSL-Bash-Terminal, it always said

```
-bash: [: too many arguments"
```

on Startup

I alredy delete the local .bashrc of my home folder, but this does not help

Iam not so familar with Bash. What can i try else?

Iam thanksful for any help

Comment: Does the message re-appear if you start another instance of the shell by typing `bash`?

Comment: yes it always re-appears when i type bash

Comment: That means you have failed to **quote** the variable within `[ ... ]` which is now expanding to multiple **words** causing `[: too many arguments" on Startup` What did you do to your `.bashrc`? Does it appear if you type `bash --norc`?

Comment: I'd try `bash -x` (enables trace mode) and see if there are any hints in the code that shows up.

Comment: Thanks for you answer.

if i type bash --norc, the message does not appear. But i also change my "prompt" from [root@myvm]# to bash-4.2#.  Dont know if this is important.

my local .bashrc is very clean just

`if [ -f /etc/bashrc]; then . /etc/bashrc fi`

Comment: If you deleted your `.bashrc`, the problem could be in `/etc/bashrc`. `bash -x` should show all the commands as they're being executed, you should be able to find the startup file that contains them.

Comment: when i type -x, the message prompts after a bunch of PATH-Variables, wich are mountend from Windows inside the WSL. if i type echo $PATH it starts with the common `bash: /usr/local/sbin/......../mnt/c/Program: No such file or directory"`   but -x show a lot more. After i write bash -x and then $PATH again, it shows all. Whats this ...

Comment: Are you entering `echo $PATH`, or just `$PATH` by itself? The first thing on the line has to be a command (or assignment); `echo` is a command, but the contents of `$PATH` is not. Also, the .bashrc contents you quoted have a syntax error: there needs to be a space between "`/etc/bashrc`" and "`]`". This doesn't match the error you report, though. Do you have a ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, or ~/.profile?

Comment: Thanks for your help. My mistake, indeed there is a space. I have typed it manually.  And i always said `$PATH` insted of `echo $PATH`. If i type it with echo, everything looks fine. Sorry :/ ...

I have in my ~ folder only a .bashrc and a .bash_profile. The .bash_profile is standard and contains the  if fi statement i posted alredy above and a `PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin` and `export PATH`

thanks for your effort

Comment: Something else interesting what i figure out.  if i write `bash -c zsh` i get the line `/etc/profile.d/puppet-agent.sh:[:3: too many arguments`  and the `./etc/profile.d/puppet-agent.sh` command i can see when i run `bash -x` . Its the command runs one line before i see the $PATH variables wich are printed by `echo $PATH`. Maybe there is a connecton?

Comment: This is the puppet-agent.sh script: https://pastebin.com/BjNn3kKh.  What i see in `bash -x` is  `./etc/profile.d/puppet-agent.sh` then i see the $PATH variables begins with a `'[' - z /usr/...`.  followed by the path variables. then it said `bash: to many arguments...`

Comment: yes the problem is the `/etc/profile-d/puppet-agent.sh` if comment it out, i dont get the bash to many arguments any more. But i need this because puppet-librarian does not work without it. Does anyone know how i can fix it?

Comment: Ok thanks for all the help. i fix it now. i just dont use puppet-agent.sh anymore and just set the puppet $PATH Variable in my ~/.bash_profile. now it works